# Is there a "moneymaker" roller-coaster in RCT3?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

I've recently reinstalled RCT3. I like the additional options that the 3-D graphics offer, but the scenarios can get very frustrating, with it being very easy to run out of money in the midst of trying to build a roller coaster to fulfill the scenario. RCT 1 and 2 had the anti-frustration feature that there were a few coasters you could build that would make their cost back fairly readily and then keep boosting your income. I haven't seemed to be able to build the same sort of profitable coaster in RCT 3.

So, is there any good money-making coaster in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping rollercoaster, powered launch @ high speed, 6-long station platform (put entrance 3rd from front), as humanly short of a track as possible while keeping the ride a little exciting (Not Low). Like ~10-15 second ride. Make sure there is a camera section on the ride. Put the ride in the busiest section of your park. You will get 3000 riders per hour if your park is busy enough. Start at $7 and work your way down as the ride gets older. Setting photo prices at $3 has worked well for me. If, say, a third of the customers get a photo, that is $8/customer, meaning $24K/hour, or $400/min, or over $5 every second.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any such roller coaster, but I never use the pre-fab coasters (where's the fun in that?). I always try to get the price for each ride as high as I can: check what people are thinking about the ride. If they say "this ride is a great value!" then bump up the price by about 0.50.  Go to fast-forward for a while then check if the people are still saying great value. If they are saying "I'm not paying that much to go on X" then you've gone too high. Usually a good roller coaster can go for 5.00-6.00 per ride, although it depends a little on the scenario (sometimes the local residents are cheapskates).

You can also do the same with all the booths. I usually don't take the time to fine-tune the price of booth items; I find I can reliably bump up the price by about 0.30 for all items whenever I build a new stall.

Don't overlook hiring enough janitors. Having a dirty park will lower your park rating significantly, which will cause people to stop coming to your park. I always fully train my janitors and give them the pay raise. They are very efficient after you do this.

Comment: I don't think I have ever used a pre-fab roller coaster either, but one thing to be careful of when building your own roller coaster is the speed at which it travels around curves and loops. If it is too fast, no one will want to ride it. I had this problem once when I accidentally made a roller coaster that experienced a max of 15 G's of force. Had to make a bunch of adjustments so people would actually ride it so I could make money.